# Are device mappings listed?

Tags: memory

There is a memory mapped device which, to my understanding, performs DMA to a ring buffer starting at address 0x7CC00000. I tried using an mmap as follows:

```
int memfd;
FILE *file;
void *ringBuffer;
char *rx;

memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
ringBuffer = mmap(0,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,memfd, 0x7CC00000);
rx = (char *)ringBuffer;

file = fopen("rx_data.dat","w");
fwrite(rx,sizeof(char),4096,file);
destroyRxBuffer(rx);
fclose(file);
sleep(5);
printf("Done.\n");
```

with the intention of reading from that ring buffer.

Using a vendor provided application, I can verify that the device is active and streaming in. What I want is to be able to grab and save the data to file, rather than just see it through the app.

The problem is, when I try saving the mmapped ring buffer, all I get are zeros, despite seeing nonzero data through the app. So my first thought is either I am using mmap incorrectly, or I am mistaken as to the location of the device's mapping. For the latter, is there anything in Linux that will show me all the mapped devices and their addresses?

Comment: I suspect that you want to use `/dev/kmem` instead of `/dev/mem` as `/dev/kmem` is a view of the kernel virtual address space and MMIO would be mapped into that virtual address space.

Comment: My system doesn't seem to HAVE /dev/kmem. Is there a workaround to use /dev/mem or would I have to get kmem?

Comment: The availability of `/dev/kmem` is based on a kernel config option, CONFIG_DEVKMEM.  If you have `/proc/config.gz`, you can do: `zgrep DEVKMEM /proc/config.gz` to see if it is enabled (`CONFIG_DEVKMEM=y` or `=m`).  If not, you'd need to rebuild the kernel with that support.

Comment: Ok, I believe I can do that. So to reiterate, you are saying the problem is the DMA address is a kernel virtual address, not a physical one, so I need to use dev/kmem to read memory based on the virtual address, correct?

Comment: Yes, but to be very clear, this is a guess on my part -- I can't guarantee you that that's the problem.